# Getting Globalize and autocomplete to work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, rails-i18n, globalize

Using globalize gem to manage translations with autocomplete, there is a situation where a number of hooks need to be properly set. Note: this does not use hstore AFAIK.  I have not managed to find a way to do so. The most productive set-up to date has
controller:

```
autocomplete :nation, :name, :full => true
```

Nation

```
translates :name
```

view

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'nation_name', '', autocomplete_nation_name_itins_path, size: 35, :id_element => 'nation_id' %>
```

There is no inherent reference to `nation_translations` database table created by `Globalize` as of yet. As this image suggests, there is a problem:

[image]

Issue 1: The input remains binded to the base table's attribute value (I have not yet cleared them out as the Globalize gem suggests.  Otherwise I'd be getting blanks). `can` is actually ready all values of `can`in master table... Typing in other locales, like cyrillic  say `Канада` has naturally no effect as that value is not part of the Nation table.

What is interesting is that the drop-down values are being populated by Rails automatically, extracting the translation values of what is input.

Issue 2:  I'd rather pass the parameter 'nation_id' which is naturally part of the nation_translations table with the form data.  although I can append `, :extra_data => [:nation_id]` to the controller  it is not being submitted (example in cyrillic where the input is given without any autocomplete)

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "nation_name"=>"Канада", "commit"=>"..."}
```

`Rails.logger.info :extra_data` returns:

```
extra_data
```

Now the second issue can be overcome because a query like

```
Nation::Translation.where('name = ?', "Канада").pluck('nation_id')
```

returns a proper result.  But that point is moot if the autocomplete is not playing ball with the user's input.

How can this be configured to have user input autocomplete with the current local translations?

Answer (score 0):

this does get solved by creating an entirely new class with attributes `nation_id, name, locale`  and can thus be called symbolically.

The query call is not that straightforward however.  As the gem suggests, the method need to be tweaked

```
def autocomplete_nation_name
  term = params[:term].downcase
  locale = params[:locale]
  nationtranslations = Nationtranslation.where('locale = ? AND name LIKE ?', locale, "%#{term}%").order(:name).all
  render :json => nationtranslations.map { |nationtranslation| {:id => nationtranslation.id, :label => nationtranslation.name, :value => nationetranslation.name} }
end
```

intervening on the action method itself provides all the leeway desired...